# MS Azure DevOps: Capturing the previous Complete Time variable when updating completed time on a task

Tags: azure-devops

I hope you are able to help me.

Goal: To track the increase of the completed work total from day to day.
Proposed solution: I have a field called [completed work] and another call [previous completed work total]. I have created a rule that states when the [completed work] is updated that the value of this field is injected into the [previous completed work total].
The issue: Both fields end up being updated with the most recent value

Is there a way I can capture the previously captured [completed work] and store this in [previous completed work total] when the [completed work] is updated ?

I have also tried to create multiple fields to capture this but it's always the same net effect

I see when i look at the history that there is a record of previous variable ( struckthrough) so i imagine it's available somehow through queries or alike ?

Thanks in advance

Neil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, there isn't a built-in feature to achieve your requirement due to Azure DevOps does not support calculated fields.

However, you can try to use external services to automate your calculation. Here is the example for your reference: [Using Microsoft Flow (Power Automate) to calculate values for fields in Azure DevOps](https://dombat.co.uk/using-microsoft-flow-to-fill-calculated-fields-in-azure-devops/)

Besides, you can also try to call the [Revisions - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/revisions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP) REST API to retrieve the `completed work` of each revision, then calculate them locally. For example, export the results to a `*.csv` file and open it with Microsoft Excel, then calculate the value in Excel.

Below PowerShell for your reference:

```
Param(
   [string]$collectionurl = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}", 
   [string]$project = "ProjectName",
   [string]$workitemid = "2329",
   [string]$user = "",
   [string]$token = "PAT"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

# Get work item history- revisions in a loop

$baseUrl = "$collectionurl/$project/_apis/wit/workitems/$($workitemid)/revisions?api-version=6.0"                   
$response = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $baseUrl -Method Get -UseDefaultCredential -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)})
$revisions = $response.value.fields #| where({$_.'System.State' -eq 'Committed'}) # Change the sate which you want to get it's changed date here 
$filename = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-M-d") + "-" + "CompleteWork"

$witrevisions = @()

foreach($revision in $revisions){

       $customObject = new-object PSObject -property @{
          "WorkItemID" = $wi
          "WorkItemType" = $revision.'System.WorkItemType'           
          "AreaPath" = $revision.'System.AreaPath'
          "TeamProject" = $revision.'System.TeamProject'
          "IterationPath" = $revision.'System.IterationPath'
          "ChangedBy" = $revision.'System.ChangedBy'.displayName
          "SystemState" = $revision.'System.State'
          "StateChangeDate" = $revision.'System.ChangedDate'
          "CompleteWork" = $revision.'Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.CompletedWork'
              } 
       
       $witrevisions += $customObject          
}
       
$witrevisions | Select-Object `
                WorkItemID,
                WorkItemType,
                AreaPath,
                TeamProject, 
                IterationPath,
                ChangedBy, 
                SystemState,
                StateChangeDate,
                CompleteWork #| export-csv -Path D:\$filename.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append # Export to CSV, then open with EXCEL
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I'll check those suggested solutions out - I have also tried to use Analytics views and export that to Power BI. Cheers